# How to provide Angular LOCALE_ID with fall back to the build configuration locale?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

This should be easy but I'm just not finding it. I think the more general question is how to conditionally override an existing provider.

I want to create a LOCALE_ID provider in my app module that can provide an overridden locale I allowed the user to set somewhere - could get it from any of several places, saved in local browser storage, loaded from a user profile by an APP_INITIALIZER, whatever. That part itself is easy, but here's what I'm missing - if I find no value, wherever I'm looking for it, I just want to default to the locale specified by the build configuration. So in other words, I want to fall back to whatever LOCALE_ID would have been provided by Angular if I hadn't created my own provider. And I don't want to use a different injection token instead of LOCALE_ID, that would require that any code needing to inject LOCALE_ID would need to know about the new custom token, and hacks to get the locale-aware pipes use the new token, etc.

Anything I try that looks for the existing LOCALE_ID injector value causes a circular DI dependency error to be thrown, which makes sense. This is what I want:

```
...
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useFactory: () => {
        const overrideLocaleId = getMyOverrideLocalIdFromSomewhere();
        if (overrideLocalId) {
          return overrideLocaleId;
        } else {
          // Return the locale specified in the build configuration, which would have
          // otherwise been provided by LOCALE_ID.
        }
      }
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm writing this question, I found what I consider a hack that seems to work, but is there a better way? This works, basically uses a static function that could get the value from someplace like a cookie or browser storage, which could have been poked into there by an app initializer if I needed something loaded from the backend. And if I find a value there, I create the provider for the LOCALE_ID token, otherwise I create it for some arbitrary token I'll never try to inject anywhere.

```
...

const DONT_PROVIDE_LOCALE_ID = new InjectionToken<string>('NeverMind');

function getCookie(name: string): string {
  // My getCookie implementation.
}

...

    {
      provide: getCookie('lang') ? LOCALE_ID : DONT_PROVIDE_LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: getCookie('lang') || 'en'
    },

...
```

Comment: You could have included this in your question instead.

Comment: Yes I could have, but they offer the option to answer your own question, and if there doesn't end up being a better answer, I want it to be here for others that find the question.